# React Native fetch() returns odd json response items

Tags: javascript, json, fetch, react-native

I'm trying to get data as JSON from service called OpenWeatherMap, so in my componentWillMount method I'm calling fetch() to return data by url. My code for now is:

`this.weather = fetch(url).then(response => response.json()).then(responseJson => responseJson);`

It works, but returns odd data within JSON response, my JSON response for now is:

`{"_40":0,"_65":1,"_55":{here_the_correct_response}}`

But I want my response to be without these strange underscore indexes, just pure JSON response

Comment: What do you mean by "pure JSON response"?

Comment: @guest271314 without these weird underscore indexes

Comment: That appears to be the response. You can parse the response and adjust the properties of the object or create a new object with adjusted property names.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out by myself. This odd data is so called promise returned by `fetch()`. In order to get rid of this I did so:

```
fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json().then(data => data))
    .then(result => /* Do whatever you want with this result */)
    .catch(error => /* Do something if error occurs */);
```

I don't know why I should do "promise decryption" twice, but it works. Any comments explaining this are appreciated.

#### UPDATE

Thanks to [vdj4y's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52846947/6375607) I now understand it correctly.

`fetch()` function is not returning a promise, as I wrote previously. It returns a `Response` object that contain information about request/response (like its statuses) and the data we need in `ReadableStream` format.

`json()` function, in turn, returns a promise that contain result of converting `ReadableStream` to plain js object. In order to manipulate data returned by promise, `then()` function is needed.

Corrected code here:

```
fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => /* Do whatever you want with this result */)
    .catch(error => /* Do something if error occurs */);
```

Comment: the second "then" does not do anything. the first then is needed, because the data that you received is on ReadableStream. Try to console.log(response).
You get the detail of your request, this could be handy when you want to track the network status or something like that. response.json(), convert the readableStream to json data. the function json() return promise.

Comment: @vdj4y Do you mean that `then(data)` aftet `json()` is unnecessary at all?

Comment: yeah, just .then(response => response.json()).then(result => {/** do something */})

Answer (score 1):

Fetch return a Response object contain some information like the request/response status. and the data that you are interested with, which was returned by server is on Response.body.

This data is ReadableStream format. The response object has function which is json(), this will return a promise that contain result of converting readablestream to js object.

If your server send invalid json. the error will occur when you run response.json(), but not before.

```
fetch(url)
  .then(response => {
     console.log(response) // this contains some useful information about the reponse
     return response.json(); // convert readable stream to js object, if json is invalid, you will get the error here
  })
  .then(result => /* Do whatever you want with this result */)
  .catch(error => /* Do something if error occurs */);
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation, appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

That behavior is correct, because `response.json()` is actually a promise.
Use `console.warn(new Promise.resolve())` to approve that. You will see a similar result.